# How to mock declared class in private method using mockito

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I am writing junit test to test the private method which has class declared in it.

My code:

```
private Object getFunctReturn()
 {
   InterfaceName obj = new ClassName():
   Map map = obj.getMap();
   map.foreach()->{
            //iterating map here....
   }
 }
```

I am using WhiteBox api to test private methods. How can I mock InterfaceName obj = new ClassName(); so that  i can proceed to for next execution of code?

Comment: Why would you want to mock it? You should only test the observable side effects. And you should not test a `private` method in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassUnderTest.class)
public class SimpleTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        ClassUnderTest underTest = new ClassUnderTest();

        ClassName obj = new ClassName();

        PowerMockito.whenNew(ClassName.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(obj);

        WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(underTest, "getFunctReturn");
    }
}
```

Comment: The ClassName implements org.eclipse.microprofile.cinfig.spi.ConfigSource interface which do not have setMap() method.

Comment: @TechP88 Removed the map call which was only there for demonstration purposes for you.